# Reversing order of integration

Tags: integration

I have to reverse the order of integration for the following problem, but the trig functions are tripping me up because I have to take domain and range restrictions into consideration.

> Calculate
>   $$\int_0^1\!\int_0^{\cos^{-1}y}\!\!\sqrt{1+\sin x}\,dx\,dy$$

Does the region of integration look like a quarter circle in the first quadrant?

Comment: Are you looking for the quarter circle in the first quadrant, meaning the unit circle?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the graph of cos x in the first quadrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the change of order

> $$ \int_0^1\!\int_0^{\cos^{-1}y}\!\!\sqrt{1+\sin x}\,dx\,dy= \int_0^{\pi/2}\!\int_0^{\cos x}\!\!\sqrt{1+\sin x}\,dy\,dx. $$

Here is the graph

[image]